# How can a US citizen obtain a Russian tourist visa from Berlin?

Tags: visas, germany, russia, us-citizens, berlin

I'm in Berlin and plan to travel to Saint Petersburg in the not-too-distant future.

How can I obtain a Russian visa while I'm in Berlin? Here are my criteria:

- Obtain a Russian tourist visa while in Berlin.
- Minimize the time I'm without a passport
- Maximize the length of my permitted stay in Russia (30 days minimum)
- Minimize paperwork / bureaucracy, I'm happy to pay an agency to handle things and expedite the process.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Russian embassy in Berlin? It's been a few years since I last got a Russian visa, but I don't get the impression it's become any easier. Still lots of paperwork and messiness. You will need an "invitation" from a hotel / tour company in Russia. These can be purchased online which makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go to the website of the [Russian embassy in Germany](http://www.russisches-konsulat.de/), you can find (although a bit hidden) a page where they state that the consular department started since 8. January 2013 to process digital visa applications coming from [Consulate Portal of Russian Foreign Affairs Ministry](https://visa.kdmid.ru/PetitionChoice.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

So if you go to that site you should be able to get your Visa

Otherwise, there are agencies like [Visa To Russia](http://www.visatorussia.com/) and [VHS](http://www.vhs-germany.com/contacts/).

Comment: The link to the consulate portal doesn't work.

Comment: I ended up going through VHS. They were really helpful on the phone and the processing fee is 25EUR.